# Binary Classification vs. Multi Class Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a machine learning classification problem with 3 possible classes (Class A, Class b and Class C). Please let me know which one would be better approach?
- Split the problem into 2 binary classification: First Identify whether it is Class A or Class 'Not A'. Then if it is Class 'Not A', then another binary classification to classify into Class B or Class C

Answer (score 1):

**Binary classification** may at the end use `sigmoid` function (goes smooth from 0 to 1). This is how we will know how to classify two values.

```
from keras.layers import Dense
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
```

For **multi class classification** you would typically use `softmax` at the very last layer, and the number of neurons in the next example will be 10, means 10 choices.

```
from keras.layers import Dropout
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu',input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

However, you can also use `softmax` with 2 neurons in the last layer for the **binary classification** as well:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

Hope this provides little intuition on classifiers.

Comment: For binary classification, out of recall and precision, which is the better matric to determine the outcome?

Comment: Hi @prosti, Kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/q/72068609/17778275

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is one method used for Multi Class Classification.
It is called One vs. All / [One vs. Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest).

The best way is to chose a good classifier framework with both options and choose the better one using Cross Validation process.