# Input shape for CNN is incompatible

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a model to predict one's emotion from the physical signals. I have three physical signals and using it as input features;

> ecg(Electrocardiography), gsr(galvanic skin response),
>   temp(temparature)

In my dataset, there are **312** records for each participant and in every record, there are **18000** rows of data. So when I combine them into a single data frame, there are **5616000** rows in total.

Here is my `x_train` dataframe;

```
           ecg     gsr   temp
0        0.1912  0.0000  40.10
1        0.3597  0.0000  40.26
2        0.3597  0.0000  40.20
3        0.3597  0.0000  40.20
4        0.3597  0.0000  40.33
5        0.3597  0.0000  40.03
6        0.2739  0.0039  40.13
7        0.1641  0.0031  40.20
8        0.0776  0.0025  40.20
9        0.0005  0.0020  40.26
10      -0.0375  0.0016  40.03
11      -0.0676  0.0013  40.16
12      -0.1071  0.0010  40.20
13      -0.1197  0.0047  40.20
..      .......  ......  .....
..      .......  ......  .....
..      .......  ......  .....
5616000 0.0226  0.1803  38.43
```

And I have 6 classes which are corresponding to emotions. I have encoded these labels with numbers;

> anger = 0, calmness = 1, disgust = 2, fear = 3, happiness = 4, sadness
>   = 5

Here is my y_train;

```
         emotion
0              0
1              0
2              0
3              0
4              0
.              .
.              .
.              .
18001          1
18002          1
18003          1
.              .
.              .
.              .
360001         2
360002         2
360003         2
.              .
.              .
.              .
.              .
5616000        5
```

To feed my CNN model, I needed to reshape my train examples. I have done it like this;

```
train_x = train_x.values.reshape(5616000,3,1) #because I have 5616000 rows and 3 input features
train_y = train_y.values.reshape(5616000,1)
```

After reshaping, I have created my CNN model;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(100,700,activation='relu',input_shape=(5616000,3)))
model.add(Conv1D(100,700,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(160,700,activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(160,700,activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])
model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs = 300, batch_size = 32, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=False)
```

And this gave me the following error;

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_96_input to have shape (5616000, 3) but got array with shape (3, 1)

Whatever I have tried, I could not make it work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try train_x = train_x.values.reshape(5616000,3)

Comment: @krisho, yes I have tried and got the following error: 
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_100_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5616000, 3)`

Comment: Do you really want to pass all your data into the model at once? Without understanding in depth what you are trying to accomplish, I would assume that you would pass each record individually, i.e. input shape would be (18000,), the training data would be of shape (312, 18000) and your labels would be of shape (312).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at `model.add(Conv1D(100,700,activation='relu',input_shape=(5616000,3)))`. Because here `input_shape` would be `(3,1)`, you have 3 input features.Use like this,

```
model.add(Conv1D(100,700,activation='relu',input_shape=(3,1)))
```

And you have `5616000` samples which can use to do `model.fit` with your selected `batch_size = 32`. So, in every iterations it will take 32 samples from 5616000 and do the training.

**Update 1**

For your use case rather to use `Conv1D`, you can use `Dense`, because you have only 3 features. I would suggest do,

```
train_x = train_x.values.reshape(5616000,3)
```

and for your `train_y`, you have 6 classes that you need to predict so, you need to do [one hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/). So, for you `train_y` will be,

```
train_y = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_y.values.reshape(5616000,1), num_classes=6)
```

And then your model would be something like this,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6,activation='softmax'))
```

Your use case is multi class classification, please find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916294/binary-classification-vs-multi-class-classification) the difference between multiclass and binary classification. Now model compile will be,

```
model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])
```

and fit will be the same,

```
model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs = 300, batch_size = 32, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=False)
```

**Update 2**

You could try this as well, if you think Dense layer is not sufficient.Because you have to add more neurons in `Dense` layer or add more hiddent layers so, you will get more number of trainable paramters and that could help. You have only three feature so, in [`Conv1D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), kernel size must be choose according to that not like this, `model.add(Conv1D(100,700,activation='relu',input_shape=(3,1)))`. I think it should also work.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(3,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(100, 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(100, 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 2, 100)            300       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 1, 100)            20100     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 1, 128)            12928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 1, 128)            16512     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 774       
=================================================================
Total params: 50,614
Trainable params: 50,614
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: After I edited my code like your answer, I am having the following error; `ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 700 from 3 for 'conv1d_104/convolution/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,3,1], [1,700,1,100].` The feature detector's size is 700 and the input is (3,1). It is causing an error.

Comment: using Dense is not useful here, I tried and got so low accuracy. I need feature detector, that's why I must use CNN.

Comment: @OzanYurtsevern Try to add more neurons in Dense layer and add few hidden layers, I think it should work.